# Adding a Custom User Action to the Android Media Session

Tags: java, android, android-auto

I'm trying to add a custom user action to my media session so that it shows up on the android auto action card, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've looked around, but didn't find much on how to explicitly add a custom action. I've included all the relevant code that is a part of my implementation of the only custom action I am trying to implement.

I would like to know what is it I'm missing and/or is doing wrong. Thank you.

```
 public class MyMediaBrowserService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat{

      //Variables Declared here ...

      @Override
      public void onCreate(){

           mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, TAG);
           mediaSessionCallback = new MyMediaSessionCallback();
           mediaSession.setCallback(mediaSessionCallback);

           // Enable callbacks from MediaButtons and TransportControls
           mediaSession.setFlags(
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
                MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

           MediaSessionCompat.Token token = mediaSession.getSessionToken();
           setSessionToken(token);

           mediaNotificationManager = new MediaNotificationManager(this);

           // Set an initial PlaybackState with ACTION_PLAY, so media 
                buttons can start the player
           mStateBuilder = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                .setActions(
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT |
                    PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)
                .addCustomAction(CUSTOM_ACTION_REPEAT, "Repeat Mode", 
                     R.drawable.ic_repeat_none);

           mediaSession.setPlaybackState(mStateBuilder.build());

           mediaSession.setActive(true);
           mediaPlayer = new DefaultMediaPlayer(this, 
                                       new DefaultMediaPlaybackListener());

      }

      ...

      public class MyMediaSessionCallback extends 
           MediaSessionCompat.Callback {

           //Variables Declared here ...

           // The following methods are actually implemented in the 
           //  project, and functions as they are supposed to.
           // They are mentioned here for the sake of showing their 
           //  existence with relations to the PlaybackStateCompat set 
           //  above.
           @Override public void onAddQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat 
                                                description) { ... }
           @Override public void onRemoveQueueItem(MediaDescriptionCompat 
                                                   description) { ... }
           @Override public void onPlayFromMediaId(String mediaId, 
                                                   Bundle extras) { .... }
           @Override public void onPlay() { ... }
           @Override public void onPause() { ... }
           @Override public void onStop() { ... }
           @Override public void onSkipToNext() { ... }
           @Override public void onSkipToPrevious() { ... }
           @Override public void onSeekTo(long pos) { ... }

           // This is the actual implement of the onCustomAction method
           // I never got it working so I figured I'll start by logging it 
           //  first before spending time coding it 
           @Override
           public void onCustomAction(String action, 
                                      Bundle extras) {

                if(action.equals(CUSTOM_ACTION_REPEAT))
                     Log.e(TAG, "Custom action is REPEAT");


           }

           ...

      }

 }
```

Comment: can you post an image of the output that you're currently getting in the playback controls? Are you using an Extras to reserve space for those slots anywhere else in the project?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

In order to add a custom action and given a `PlayBackStateCompat.Builder` you can add a custom action as follows:

```
mStateBuilder.addCustomAction(
            new PlaybackStateCompat.CustomAction.Builder(
                    CUSTOM_ACTION_REPLAY,
                    getString(R.string.custom_action_replay),
                    R.drawable.ic_replay).build()
    );
```

Then you must add the code to handle the custom action as you already did.
The code above should work, and correctly display the actions on Android Auto, i use this to display the custom action. Hope this helps even if i am little late